# I am stuck with the following problem on Real Analysis.I need help.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $G$ be an open set in $\mathbb R$ such that $0\not\in G$ and $H=\{x \cdot y \mid x,y\in G\}$.
Prove that $H$ is open in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: What have you tied?

Answer (score 1):

You know that for every $x \in G$ there is an open interval $I$ containing $x$ and being a subset of $G$. Likewise for $y \in G.$ You should show that if $z \in H$ then there is some interval $J$ containing $z$ and being a subset of $H.$

Therefore, take a $z \in H.$ What do you know about $z$ in terms of $G$?

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is open, then $H=G \cdot G$ is open.

Note that $a G$ is open for all $a\neq 0$ because the map $x \mapsto ax$ is a homeomorphism.

If $0 \notin G$, then $H = \cup_{a \in G} a G$ and so $H$ is open.

If $0 \in G$, then $0G = \{0\}$ and $0 \in aG$ for all $a$, and so $H = \cup_{a \in G\setminus \{0\}} a G$ and so $H$ is open.

Comment: It's not true that $aG$ is open for all $a$. If $a=0$ then $aG = \{0\}$ which is *not* open.

Comment: Also, $x \mapsto ax$ is not a homeomorphism if $a = 0$.